# Accessing Old PHP Sessions from Zend framework

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I have an old code base and I've installed a zf2 application inside the same folder.
While going in zend and for authentication purpose, I would like to check if the session is active from my main application so I re-authenticate the user in zend.

How can I access the already existing session parameters from my zend application as it seems zend has it's own storage and start a new session base itself?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just access the session normally with `$_SESSION`, get it's keys and data and dump it into a Zend Session?

Example:

```
use Zend\Session\Container as SessionContainer;

// say the old user session is an array
// array(
//     'name' => 'john',
//     'key2' => 'val2',
// );

// access the old data normally
$old_user_data = $_SESSION['user'];

// create a new session container with "old_data" as the namespace
$session = new SessionContainer('old_data'); 

// now since this is an old "user" info just set the key to be "user" in 
// this namespace
$session->user = $old_sess_data;
```

That would look like this in the session:

```
[old_data] => Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject Object
    (
        [storage:protected] => Array
            (
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        name => john,
                        key2 => val2,
                    )

            )

        [flag:protected] => 2
        [iteratorClass:protected] => ArrayIterator
        [protectedProperties:protected] => 
    )
```

Now if you already have an existing Zend Session, then just go ahead and retrieve your old session data just like in the above example and push it to whatever existing namespace that already exists.